# SharePoint Event receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I have created a sharepoint item updating event receiver for a custom list. The event receiver checks certain condition and block the user from saving the item if the condition fails. TO display the warning, i have used

```
 properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    properties.errormessage= "error";
```

Now it shows error message below the form in red font. I want to change the formatting of the text, and want to show the error message in bold characters. How can this be achieved, any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you inspect the html, you will find something that might help

```
span[role="alert"]
{
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

you can apply this css locally (CEWP) or globally (master page/alternatecssurl reference)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one instead

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "Error";
properties.Cancel = true;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CanceWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = "your custom error page"
```

You can find more information [here](https://waelmohamed.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/create-custom-error-page-for-sharepoint-event-receiver/)

Comment: I do not want to redirect on to the different page, instead I want to  show on the same edit form